# Two Listboxes with same value, I need to remove identicial value from one Listbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have two ASP ListBoxes. As you can see below, lbAvailable is populated on PageLoad with WebMethod and populates all cities. LbChoosen is populated depending on DropDown Value Chosen. The Dropdown has 4 options(ALL, Top25, Top50, Top100). for example if you choose Top 25 which is value 4, lbChosen populates top 25 cities (This all works).

MY PROBLEM IS lbAvaliable always populates all cities. So if i chose top 25 which populates top25 cities into lbChoosen, how can those value (top25 cities) be removed from lbAvailable

```
function LoadMarketsAvailableJS() {
var ddlFootprint = $('#ddlFootprint');
var lbChoosen = $('#lbChoosen');
var lbAvailable = $('#lbAvailable');
lbChoosen.empty();

var SelectedMarkets = [];
var url = "";

 //Load lbAvailable on Page Load with all Markets
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Campaign.aspx/LoadAvailableMarkets",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.Markets.length; i++) {
        if (SelectedMarkets.indexOf(obj.Markets[i].id.toString()) == -1) {
    $("#lbAvailable").append($("<option></option>")
   .attr("value",          obj.Markets[i].id)
   .text(obj.Markets[i].name + " - " + obj.Markets[i].rank));

    }
        }
            },
    error: function(result) {
    alert("Error");
    }
});


//Check DropdownList
if (parseInt(ddlFootprint.val()) == 1) {
    url = 'Campaign.aspx/LoadAvailableMarkets';
} else if (parseInt(ddlFootprint.val()) == 2) {
    url = 'Campaign.aspx/LoadTop100Markets';
}
else if (parseInt(ddlFootprint.val()) == 3) {
    url = 'Campaign.aspx/LoadTop50Markets';
}
else if (parseInt(ddlFootprint.val()) == 4) {
    url = 'Campaign.aspx/LoadTop25Markets';
}
else if (parseInt(ddlFootprint.val()) == 5) {
    url = 'Campaign.aspx/LoadAvailableMarkets';
}
//Load Select Dropdown Value to lbChoosen
if (url.length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.Markets.length; i++) {
                if (SelectedMarkets.indexOf(obj.Markets[i].id.toString()) == -1) {
                    lbChoosen
                        .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", obj.Markets[i].id)
                        .text(obj.Markets[i].name + " - " + obj.Markets[i].rank));
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood what you're asking, if you want to remove options from lbAvailable as they're added to lbChoosen you should be add the following line:

```
lbAvailable.find('option[value="' + obj.Markets[i].id + '"]').remove();
```

So your code will look something like:

```
success: function (msg) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.Markets.length; i++) {
        if (SelectedMarkets.indexOf(obj.Markets[i].id.toString()) == -1) {
            lbChoosen
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", obj.Markets[i].id)
                .text(obj.Markets[i].name + " - " + obj.Markets[i].rank));
            lbAvailable.find('option[value="' + obj.Markets[i].id + '"]').remove();
        }
    }
},
```